# Scala Import of Object in Same File

Tags: scala, spray

I am new to scala and a bit confused on some syntax mojo.

I am writing a spray rest service.  To specify how a custom object is marshaled to JSON I created the following:

```
  object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit object PersonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Person] {
      def write(p: Person) =JsObject(
        "name" -> JsString(p.name),
        "fname" -> JsString(p.firstName)
      )

      def read(value: JsValue) = {
        value.asJsObject.getFields("name", "firstName", "age") match {
          case Seq(JsString(name), JsString(firstName), JsNumber(age)) =>
            new Person(name, firstName, age.toInt)
          case Seq(JsString(name), JsString(firstName)) =>
            new Person(name, firstName, 0)
          case _ => throw new DeserializationException("Person expected: " + value.asJsObject.getFields("name", "firstName", "age").toString)
        }
      }
    }

}
```

If I include this at the top of my Akka actor subclass, why would i need to include the line

```
import MyJsonProtocol._
```

For it to be seen in the same file?  Normally imports are external references and a class or object which appears in the same file as another class can be referenced without such measures.

Thanks for any help.
Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up what is visible in what scope:

Nested objects or classes or classes have access to all vals, nested classes and objects of their surrounding scope, not the other way around. And I don't know any language, where this is different.

```
object Outer {
  val foo = "bar"

  object Intermediate {
    object Innermost {
      println(foo)
    }
  }
}
```

`foo` is in the cope of `Innermost` because it is nested within the scope of `foo` itself. However,

```
object Outer {
  object Intermediate {
    object Innermost {
      val foo = "bar"
    }
  }

  println(foo)
}
```

Won't work because foo is hidden deeper in the nested scopes.

Let's rewrite the example:

```
  object Intermediate 

  object Innermost {
    val bar = "foo"
  }

  object Outer {
    val interm = Intermediate
    val inner = Innermost

    println(Innermost.bar)
  }
```

In this case it is obvious how we have to access bar.

Although, the previous example looks pretty different, it isn't really that different. To access 'foo' one would have to drill down to it

```
object Outer {
  object Intermediate {
    object Innermost {
      val foo = "bar"
    }
  }

  println(Intermediate.Innermost.foo)
}
```

I hope now you see why you have to drill down to `MyJsonProtocol.PersonFormat` to have it in your scope.

Comment: I've never heard of an OOP language that didn't have this type of scoping, but I do know of functional languages that have different scoping (various LISP implementations come to mind).

Comment: So I guess my confusion is in the back of my head I am considering it a global var since it is being instantiatiated in the same file as the class that references it.